# Problem rebuilding formats in MiKTeX for special characters in hyphenation patterns

Tags: miktex

I am trying to add hyphenation for the albanian language. After modifying languages.ini and adding the appropriate files, format is having problems reading two letters in patterns (ë and ç).

This was added in `language.ini` :

```
[albanian]
loader=loadhyph-al.tex
lefthyphenmin=2
righthyphenmin=2
patterns=hyph-al.pat.txt
hyphenation=hyph-al.hyp.txt
```

This is the content of `loadhyph-al.tex` :

```
\begingroup
\lccode`\'=`\'
% Test for pTeX
\ifx\kanjiskip\undefined
% Test for native UTF-8 (which gets only a single argument)
% That's Tau (as in Taco or ΤΕΧ, Tau-Epsilon-Chi), a 2-byte UTF-8 character
\def\testengine#1#2!{\def\secondarg{#2}}\testengine Τ!\relax
\ifx\secondarg\empty
    % Unicode-aware engine (such as XeTeX or LuaTeX) only sees a single (2-byte) argument
    \message{UTF-8 Albanian hyphenation patterns}
    \input hyph-al.tex
    \input hyph-quote-al.tex
\else
    % 8-bit engine (such as TeX or pdfTeX)
    \message{ASCII Albanian hyphenation patterns}
    \input hyph-al.tex
\fi\else
    % pTeX
    \message{ASCII Albanian hyphenation patterns}
    \input hyph-al.tex
\fi
\endgroup
```

This is the content of `hyph-al.tex` :

```
\patterns{
.bashkë1
.dh2
.fj8
.çm8 }
```

This is the content of `hyph-quote-al.tex` :

```
\bgroup
\lccode`\’=`\’
\patterns{
2’2
2ç’
2sh’
4s’
2t’
}
\egroup
```

This is the content of `hyph-al.pat.txt` :

```
.bashkë1
.dh2
.fj8
.çm8
```

And `hyph-al.hyp.txt` is empty.

The letter ë is not recognized as according to log :

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\hyph-utf8\patterns\tex\hyph-al.tex"

! Nonletter.

l.45 .bashkÃ

            «1

Sorry, but miktex-makefmt did not succeed for the following reason:

miktex-pdftex.exe failed on etex.ini.
```

Can I add something there so ë and ç are recognized ?

Checked hyph-tr.tex (turkish) and hyph-fr.tex (french) but they simply use special characters with no problems.

[EDIT] After solving the formatting error, LuaLaTex recognized the new language, but not XeLaTeX.

The document :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{albanian}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Answer when compiling with XeLaTex :

```
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `Albanian'

(polyglossia)      I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on input line 8.


Package polyglossia Warning: \setlocalhyphenmin useless for unhyphenated language albanian on input line 8.
```

Answer when compiling with LuaLaTex :

```
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-albanian.ldf"
Language data for albanian loader loadhyph-al.tex
righthyphenmin 2
lefthyphenmin 2
patterns hyph-al.pat.txt
hyphenation hyph-al.hyp.txt
synonyms table: 0000018D1841DD20

hyph-al.pat.txt
Language albanian was not yet loaded; created with id 4
Language albanian already loaded; id is 4
Language albanian already loaded; id is 4) (./test-hyphenation2.aux
Language albanian already loaded; id is 4)
```

Comment: Do you have written a loader file? (see e.g. loadhyph-fr.tex). Side remark: You shouldn't put your local files in C:\Program Files, and also not in the original hyph-utf8-folders.

Comment: yes created loadhyph-al.tex hyph-al.tex hyph-al.pat.txt and hyph-quote-al.tex. I will transfer them later to local folders, for the moment I just wanted to test

Comment: Well without all the files and the exact content of your languages.ini I can't test.

Comment: try a hyph-al.tex with only those 4 patterns, or I can upload them somewhere..

Comment: Why should I spent my time to build up a test environment? It is your problem.

Comment: I actually am not sure testing would add more information than I provided, but let me build a zip with what I modified..

Comment: Better than a zip file would be a MWE. Provide the contents of the smallest possible files containing the problem, and also specify the program invocation with which you try to build the format.

Comment: Ok I can modify the question here with the content of the most important files..

Comment: No not only the most important files but *all* files. I don't want to have to guess what you have done and if there is perhaps a colon too much in your text somewhere. And unlike Harald I think a zip is better as the actual encoding of the files can matter and copy & paste is not realiable.

Comment: I am also making a zip with the files.. Idk if I can upload it though

Comment: You are missing `\input conv-utf8-ec.tex` for the 8-bit engines.

Comment: Where should I add that ? (uploading zips seems quite complicated)

Comment: [Edit] Never mind, that was it for formatting. THANKS. The language is not loaded yet though. Please, can you post an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `loadhyph-al.tex` you are missing to load conv-utf8-ec.tex which adds the definitions for the non-ascii letters:

```
\else
    % 8-bit engine (such as TeX or pdfTeX)
    \message{ASCII Albanian hyphenation patterns}
     \input conv-utf8-ec.tex %<-----------
    \input hyph-al.tex
\fi
```

Side remark: The ptex-case normally needs its own set of hyphenation patterns (see e.g. the french loader, where hyph-fr.ec.tex is used here). If you don't want to create them, it would be imho better to simply remove this case. Better no pattern than wrong patterns,

Comment: Ok I will remove ptex. LuaLaTex/polyglossia is recognizing the language but not XeLaTex/polyglossia, any idea ?

Comment: Did you build the xelatex format?

Comment: I used MiKTeX Options (Admin)/Update formats. Xelatex showed last in the little window while working.

Comment: Add your tex document.

Comment: Added the tex document. Meanwhile the turkish patterns are a smarter example of what I should have done, maybe will rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Your files works fine for me. Imho you haven't correctly (re)-created the format. If in doubt do it with the user version of miktex settings -- user files shadows admin files.